# Check for misspelt words using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, search, instant

I am using this code to create an instant search for my site...

http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/

Some of the phrases in our database our very complex and can be easily misspelt so on top of this I wanted to use spelling suggestions.

Does anyone know of any ways to offer correct spellings based on a string provided?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone searches for a phrase, doesn't click any of the results, and then researches with a new similar phrase (check out [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)) and *does* click a result, write to your database the original phrase and the new phrase.

Record each time this happens. If the phrase is already matched, increment a counter for that phrase.

Then, if someone searches for a phrase that matches one of your *possibly incorrect* phrases (perhaps have a threshold using your counter), you can display a *Did you mean to search for...?* as well as the results (if any) for the incorrect phrase.

This isn't a spell check per se, but I think it would be useful to pick up on common mistakes. Unfortunately though, you probably don't have as many people to help you build an index like Google's *Did you mean?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a jQuery plugin called [After the Deadline](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AtD).

Comment: would it pick up on words such as "Glucosamine"

Comment: I'm not sure, for complex words like that I would use levenshtein as suggested below, or even better, both.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Norvig has written (and explained) a fairly basic [spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html); which makes for a very interesting read. It's in Python, but his explanations are invaluable (He does work for Google and this is a very bare bones representation of the Google *did you mean* algorithm).